# html/javascript hover menu

Tags: javascript, html, menu

I have already got a nav menu at the top of my page, but now I am trying to expand a sub menu when I hover over one of these options. My first idea was to simply have a "div" section of the code like such

```
<div id= "expanded_menu"> <!-- sub menu option --> </div>
```

and show/hide it based on whether it's nav option was hovered over, but then I realized that the submenu would disappear as soon as I took my mouse off of it's corresponding nav menu button. Does anyone know a way to hover over an option, have that bring up a menu, and then be able to access the submenu without it disappearing?

Comment: Use a script and/or style that's already been developed and implemented. [Suckerfish](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/), for instance.

Comment: You can achieve this with CSS only, no need for javascript here. Try this tutorial http://www.seoconsultants.com/css/menus/tutorial/ Here's the working example: http://ago.tanfa.co.uk/css/examples/menu/hs7.html

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to do this is with nested lists...

```
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li>
        First menu item
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>Sub menu item</li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>Second menu item</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

And use the following CSS.

```
.sub-menu { display: none; }
#main-menu li:hover .submenu { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the sub-menu is nested in the parent menu item's div, your method should work. So your HTML structure would be:

```
<div class="main_menu_item">MainItem
    <div class="sub_menu_item">Item1</div>
    <div class="sub_menu_item">Item2</div>
</div>
```

Then you're still hovering on the main item when hovering on the sub-items.

However, I personally would implement this all in CSS -- search for "CSS menus" and you'll find a ton of resources.